# Routes don't work when default define in ASP.net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have an MVC4 aplications with my routes defined in the RouteConfig working ok, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "LocalizedDefault", "{lang}/{homePage}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", pageCode = "home" },
    new {lang = @"(en|es)", homePage = @"(home|inicio)"}
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Flowers",
    "{lang}/{page}",
    new {controller = "Plants", action = "Flowers", pageCode = "flowers"},
    new {lang = @"(en|es)", page= @"(flowers|flores)"}
);

/* ... more routes ... */

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

as you can see every route has a parameter I need to change my languages (my business logic), the problem is that when I put the url without any parameters like http://www.mydomain.com, it loads my default page but I can't change the language because I don't have my page Parameter, then I change my routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Flowers",
    "{lang}/{page}",
    new {controller = "Plants", action = "Flowers", pageCode = "flowers"},
    new {lang = @"(en|es)", page= @"(flowers|flores)"}
);

/* ... more routes ... */

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{lang}/{page}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", pageCode = "home" },
    new {lang = @"(en|es)", page = @"(home|inicio)"}
);
```

Now I have my site changing its language ok when call http://www.mydomain.com but the others routes don't work anymore (ex: http://www.mydomain.com/en/flowers)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the default route and add a parameter to your url like this...

```
http://mydomain.com/?lang=es
```

Then on you Index action at your home controller...

```
public ActionResult Index(String? lang){
    //do some stuff when lang != null
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I can't add that parameter

Comment: By calling the full path mydomain.com/home/index?lang=es ?

Comment: no, I was clear, it works ok with this mydomain.com/es/inicio and mydomain.com/en/home .... but I also need mydomain.com to work

Comment: You can make a redirection to a default language in the index action of the home controller. return RedirectToRoute(routeName);